# How to Insert/Update the data from Microsoft Excel sheet to Mysql Database?

Tags: mysql, excel

How to Insert/Update the data from Microsoft Excel sheet to Mysql Database?
i wants to insert two fields into a particular table, from excel sheet.

**For Example:** i have two fields in mysql db. (1). Emp id (2). Emp name

Now i need to insert emp id and emp name from  excel sheet. i don't wants to use any programming language, i just need to insert into particular table by using excel data.

can you please suggest any queries

Comment: This question is unclear. Can you please state - programming language, what you are trying to achieve, what have you tried?

Comment: i tried to update the mysql database from excel sheet data. is there any easy query to do this @LittlePanda

Comment: How did you try the update? Which programming language? Please give us all the necessary information.

Comment: @LittlePanda i edited my question.kindly check it

Comment: Ok. I think you should go through this link - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html

Answer (score -1):

Export excel book as .cvs and inport it into mysql